# Remove new lines within and around a specific text blok

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a text files that contains similar text (I placed `\n` as an indicator of new line, so it does not exists withing a text):

```
\n
---
\n
\n
not fixed
number of 
lines
\n
\n
---
\n
Other text
\n
More text
\n
\n
...
```

The text between triple lines is not fixed, could be many lines of text there.
I want to remove all the new lines within and on the top of the triple lines:

```
---
not fixed
number of 
lines
---

Other text

More text


...
```

Currently I found how to delete the first line, but I am struggling to think how to omit the rest:

```
myText = myText.split('\n').slice(1).join('\n'));
```

I tried to use this regex recomended in answer `const s2 = s1.replace( /\n+---\n+/g , '\n---\n' );` but the problem is that it produces the following result:

```
\n
---
not fixed
number of 
lines
---
Other text
\n
More text
\n
\n
...
```

But what I want is:

```
---
not fixed
number of 
lines
---
\n
\n
Other text
\n
More text
\n
\n
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `myText.replace(/^\n/gm, "")`

Example/Demo:

```js
let text = `
---


not fixed
number of 
lines


---

Other text
More text`;

console.log(text.replace(/^\n/gm, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to do you:

```
const s1 = "...";
const s2 = s1.replace( /\n+---\n+/g , '\n---\n' ) ;
```

Comment: it kind of works, but it adds one new line in the top of the first triple lines and removes new lines after the second triple dash that I want to keep. I updated the question where I describe the situation with you regex in more details